# Pysphere get current snapshot name

Tags: python, vsphere, pysphere

Does anybody know how to get current snapshot name, using pyshpere api?
https://code.google.com/p/pysphere/wiki/GettingStarted#List_snapshots

Comment: I didn't find such option only to get all snapshots , delete current snapshot or revert to it

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # This ignores the certificate warning
    default_context = ssl._create_default_https_context
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

    # Connect to the VMware instance
    server_instance = pysphere.VIServer();
    server_instance.connect(ipaddress,username,password)

    # Create a VM object of which details are required
    vm = server_instance.get_vm_by_name(vmname)

    # This gets the status of the VM.
    print vm.get_status()

    # This gets the current snapshot name.
    print vm.get_current_snapshot_name()
```

It's always a good idea to refer to the basic libraries. Here is the link for pysphere. [http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@p@y@pysphere-HEAD@pysphere@**init**.py/173/pysphere.vi_mor.MORTypes](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@p@y@pysphere-HEAD@pysphere@__init__.py/173/pysphere.vi_mor.MORTypes)

Good luck!